# Simpledateformat - Why Calendar.MONTH wrongly generate previous month value(ie Dec-2015) for January'16?

Tags: java, calendar, simpledateformat

I have been trying to get the past 12 months values from current month, using Simpledateformat. But for previous month(ie Dec-2015) i always get Dec-2016.

calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, -1); 
This is supposed to return Dec-2015, but its not.

I dont understand the logic. Could someone please explain. Thanks a lot for your time and help.

My Code:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    SimpleDateFormat month_date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM-YYYY");

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, -1);


        String month_name = month_date.format(calendar.getTime());
        System.out.println("month_name : "+month_name);

}
```

Output:

```
month_name : Dec-2016
```

Comment: instead of set calendar, try to add months integer value. if you want past month then add negative value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with the code.

1) You should use add `calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);` to subtract the month.

2) Interestingly after that too it would print the output as `month_name : Dec-2016` this is because your `SimpleDateFormat` has an issue, i.e. you have mentioned the year as capital `Y` which is `Week year` changing it to `y` will do the job.

You can refer to the `SimpleDateFormat` documentation [here.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

The modified code will be:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
         SimpleDateFormat month_date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM-yyyy");
         Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
         calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);

         String month_name = month_date.format(calendar.getTime());
         System.out.println("month_name : "+month_name);
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

To substrack months you can do this:

```
calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
```

Hope it helps you.